# \usepackage{siunitx} gives errors when used with math code in tabularx

Tags: siunitx

I want to use `siunitx` package for writing the units in my document. However, just adding the line:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

to the document (and without even using the `siunitx` commands) gives 84 errors of the type: `Missing '}'... Missing '$' ... Extra '}' ...` and so on.

Without this line the document compiles and generated fine.

I have managed to locate the source causing the problem, which is the use of math code inside a tabularx.

Here is minimal code to compile:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.25\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
\begin {table}[h]
\caption{Comparison between bla bla bla}
\centering
{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.95\linewidth} {Y|s}   
    \hline\hline
    column 1 title & column 2 title \tabularnewline % [0.5cm]  
    \hline%\hline
    cell(1,1) & $\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline
%\begin{comment}
    cell(2,1) & $\frac{\textrm{w}_0}{\sqrt{2}}\approx 0.7\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline
    cell(3,1) & $\frac{\textrm{w}_0}{\sqrt{3}}\approx 0.58\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline
    cell(4,1) & $0.5\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline
    cell(5,1) & $0.46\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline

    \hline
%\end{comment}
    \end{tabularx}
}
\label{tab:comparing_table}
\end{table} 
%
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

Now, without the: `\usepackage{siunitx}` the above table compiles just fine.
The problem is with the math code inside the table. The same table with text only also compiles fine.

How can I keep the table with the math in it and with `siunitx` ???

Comment: it is presumably a clash with some other package but as you give no indication of your input it is impossible to guess, please try to construct the smallest example that you can that has the error and add to your question.

Comment: It's more likely that you have some syntax error that you typed at the same time you added the package.  Find where in your tex file the first error occurs, and the error will likely be nearby.

Comment: It is a thesis document, very long and using a lot of packages. How can I pinpoint which one is cuasing the problem ? ?

Comment: it is much easier for you to do it than anyone else:-) first start with a document that has your thesis preamble but no content other than the table. Check that gives the error. If it does not, then the error is not in the table...., if it does , delete every usepackage line that is loading packages not used in the table, until you get a small example that shows the error. If you delete a package and the error goes, that is the problem...

Comment: Unlikely that it is a syntax error since I commented the whole line and then the document compiled, and when I wrote again very carefully the '\usepackage{siunitx}' in a new line, I again got the 84 errors.

Comment: the count of errors is very rarely  meaningful as if you scroll past the first error in tex, then the error recovery does not usually do anything sensible so all later errors are often spurious.

Comment: To what table are you referring David?

Comment: Oh I was assuming you had an error in a table from siunitx `S` columns forget "table" but just have whatever paragraph or equation or whatever is causing the error (the error message log will show the filename and line number of the first error, so basically you just need that line plus whatever else you need to make it a valid latex document.

Comment: I think the 'comment' package made the errors. When I eliminated it (and also some chapters that use the comment package extensively) the compilation errors gone. Is there a way around the problem so I can also use the 'comment' package?

Comment: Try to come up with a very small document that reproduces the error for you .... and will let us reproduce the error. If there is something going on, a user will find a solution for it. Hint: Edit the question to add that small document (called a minimal working example).

Comment: please make a small compilable example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Don't put a `center` environment around the `table` environment, that defeats the purpose of floats.

Comment: I have edited the question to include a small compilable example that reproduces my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem comes from your custom `columntype` since using `j` instead of `s` works flawless for me.
The `s` is reserved by the `siunitx` package.

[image: tabularx]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{j}{>{\hsize=.25\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Comparison between bla bla bla}
\centering
{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % 
    \begin{tabularx}{0.95\linewidth}{Y|j}   
    \hline\hline
    column 1 title & column 2 title \tabularnewline % [0.5cm]  
    \hline%\hline
    cell(1,1) & {$\textrm{w}_0$}  \tabularnewline
    cell(2,1) & $\frac{\textrm{w}_0}{\sqrt{2}}\approx 0.7\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline
    cell(3,1) & $\frac{\textrm{w}_0}{\sqrt{3}}\approx 0.58\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline
    cell(4,1) & $0.5\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline
    cell(5,1) & $0.46\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\label{tab:comparing_table}
\end{table} 
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The console output (and the log file) shows

```
Package array Warning: Column s is already defined on input line 8.
```

When a column type is already defined, `array` usually warns and overwrites the definition. But Catch 22 is there waiting for us! The `s` column type is defined by `siunitx`, so the warning is shown, but `siunitx` actually does the necessary definition for the column type at begin document! So you end up anyway with the `s` column type defined by `siunitx` and this causes the error, because the input in that column is invalid.

If you aren't sure that overwriting a column type is safe, don't do it.

There are a few other points to note.

1. Never place `table` inside `center`: this has the only effect of producing unwanted vertical space in the document and the table may or may not be in the middle of that vertical space.
2. Avoid `\begin{table}[h]` in the hope the float will actually be placed *here*. It usually won't. LaTeX converts `[h]` to `[ht]`, but big floats might not find their place in the specified positions and you end up delaying it and all subsequent floats until the end of the current chapter.
3. Using a group to localize the effect of `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` is useless, because the former value will be restored anyway after `\end{table}`.
4. Put your `\label` next to the `\caption`, which it belongs to.
5. The correct way to go for using “variable `X` columns” is to use `\hsize=<frac>\hsize` so that the sum of all fractions is the total number of `X` columns. In your case if the subdivision is 3/4 for the first column and 1/4 for the second column it should be

   ```
   >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X
   ```

Full code, with `booktabs` features rather than `\hline\hline` and vertical rules.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Comparison between bla bla bla}
\label{tab:comparing_table}

\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{tabularx}{0.95\linewidth}
 {
  >{\centering\hsize=1.5\hsize}X
  >{\centering\hsize=0.5\hsize}X
 }
\toprule
column 1 title & column 2 title \tabularnewline % [0.5cm]  
\midrule
    cell(1,1) & $\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline
%\begin{comment}
    cell(2,1) & $\frac{\textrm{w}_0}{\sqrt{2}}\approx 0.7\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline
    cell(3,1) & $\frac{\textrm{w}_0}{\sqrt{3}}\approx 0.58\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline
    cell(4,1) & $0.5\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline
    cell(5,1) & $0.46\textrm{w}_0$ \tabularnewline

\bottomrule
%\end{comment}
\end{tabularx}

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the output with

```
>{\centering}X c
```

for the column specifications:

[image]